# spring security in rest Web service

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement spring security in restweb service.

I am always getting "*Entering commence due to failed Authentication*" message. It is not going in `CustomAuthenticationProvider.java`. My code returns me from `CustomEntryPoint`. I think there's a misconfiguration.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value> WEB-INF/security-config.xml

        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

      <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/security-config.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

   <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
     </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 

<!--   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list> -->
<!-- Tag Libary -->

</web-app>
```

**Spring security file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <sec:http entry-point-ref="customEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">

        <sec:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter"
            before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />

        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="hasAuthority('AUTH_USER')" />

        <sec:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />

        <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
    </sec:http>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.arpit.java2blog" />

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="org.arpit.java2blog" /> -->

    <beans:bean id="authenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="postOnly" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customSuccessHandler" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="customSuccessHandler"   class="org.arpit.java2blog.controller.CustomSuccessHandler" />
        <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"   class="org.arpit.java2blog.controller.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />

</beans:beans>
```

**Class files**

```
package org.arpit.java2blog.controller;

import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) 
      throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = auth.getName();
        String password = auth.getCredentials()
            .toString();
        System.out.println(username +"::"+password);

        if ("user".equals(username) && "pass".equals(password)) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
              (username, password, Collections.emptyList());
        } else {
            throw new
              BadCredentialsException("External system authentication failed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return auth.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}

package org.arpit.java2blog.controller;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint
{

        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException
        {
                    System.out.println("Entering commence due to failed Authentication");
                 response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized Access!" );
        }

}

package org.arpit.java2blog.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;


public class CustomSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
                System.out.println("authentication successful!");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are braking filter chain with that customEntryPoint because it is run before any authentification and since it sends response.sendError, chain if broken. So, remove that entry point bean.
You can register custom success and failure handlers by adding this inside sec:http secition:

```
<sec:form-login
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailedHandler"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

where success handler is:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // success
    }
}
```

and failed handler:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailedHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);    
        // failed
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.